# Angular 7: Using a mat-select: Getting the options for mat-option dynamically creates a never ending loop

Tags: angular

The goal is to change the options for my dropdown depending on some conditions in my angular component.
The html looks like this:

```
                <mat-label>{{jobStatus}}</mat-label>
                <mat-select [formControl]="jobStatusModificationControl" panelClass="mcCoyDropDown">
                  <mat-option *ngFor="let option of getJobStatusModificationOptions()" [value]="option.value"
                    (onSelectionChange)="changeJobStatus($event)">
                    {{option.option}}
                  </mat-option>
                </mat-select>
              </mat-form-field>
```

The component looks like this:

```
getJobStatusModificationOptions() {
    let jobStatusModificationOptions = [
      { option: "Close Job", value: JobStatusEnum.Closed },
      { option: "Activate Job", value: JobStatusEnum.Active }
    ];

    if (this.jobStatus == JobStatusEnum.Closed) {
      jobStatusModificationOptions = [
        { option: "Open Job", value: JobStatusEnum.Closed },
        { option: "Activate Job", value: JobStatusEnum.Active }
      ];
    }
    else if (this.jobStatus == JobStatusEnum.Active) {
      jobStatusModificationOptions = [
        { option: "Close Job", value: JobStatusEnum.Closed },
        { option: "Open Job", value: JobStatusEnum.Opened }
      ];
    }
    return jobStatusModificationOptions;
```

So depending on the conditions, the jobStatusModificationOptions will change.  I only call this function in the html and not in the ngOnInit().
The result is a never ending look.  I can put a break point at the line return jobStatusModificationOptions and hit it all day long.

Is there a way to set these mat-options dynamically or do I need to set up 3 drop downs and use ngFor with the conditions.  I did not want to do it that way because it is so messy.

Comment: I assume it's just the angular lifecircle, which is checking all the time for changes of variables. I would suggest, that you create and set the option `jobStatusModificationOptions`  within `changeJobStatus` instead of calling a method within the `ngFor`.

Comment: @Paul The changeJobStatus method is only triggered after the jobStatusModificationOptions have been defined,  right?

Comment: Yes, you would need to initialize it in the constructor or directly when declaring the property and then change it within the changeJobStatus method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that every time `getJobStatusModificationOptions()` is called it returns a new pointer despite internal data is the same.

try to keep pointer of the returned value between calls the same if data is the same.

For example like that:

```js
private readonly statuses = {
    [JobStatusEnum.Closed]: [
        {option: "Open Job", value: JobStatusEnum.Closed},
        {option: "Activate Job", value: JobStatusEnum.Active},
    ],
    [JobStatusEnum.Active]: [
        {option: "Close Job", value: JobStatusEnum.Closed},
        {option: "Open Job", value: JobStatusEnum.Opened},
    ],
    [JobStatusEnum.Opened]: [
        {option: "Close Job", value: JobStatusEnum.Closed},
        {option: "Activate Job", value: JobStatusEnum.Active},
    ]
};

getJobStatusModificationOptions() {
    if (this.jobStatus == JobStatusEnum.Closed) {
        return this.statuses[JobStatusEnum.Closed];
    }
    if (this.jobStatus == JobStatusEnum.Active) {
        return this.statuses[JobStatusEnum.Active];
    }
    return return this.statuses[JobStatusEnum.Opened];
}
```

Now angular can detect that the returned value hasn't been changed and skip rerender.